# Accessing Objective-C Instance in Wax

Tags: ios, lua, iphone-wax

There are some use cases I want to create instance of certain objects 
in objc and access them in Lua/Wax. 
I read the entire documentation but I'm still uncertain how to 
accomplish this.

**Some Demo Code** (doesn't work, but you should get the idea)

```
galaxy = UIApplication:sharedApplication():delegate():galaxy() 
starclusters = galaxy:starclusters() 
galaxy_drawing = 
UIApplication:sharedApplication():delegate():galaxyDrawing() 
function set_starcluster_position_in_galaxy (x) 
starclusters:objectAtIndex(0):setValue_forKey("position_in_galaxy_x", 
300) 
    puts("Setting Starcluster Position X") 
end
```

> **Disclaimer**: I'm seeding some Google Groups iPhone Wax Questions on
>   Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Wax Developer Corey wrote

> If galaxy:starclusters() returns an
>   NSArray, wax will automatically change
>   this to a Lua array. This might be the
>   problem
>
> If you want to directly change the
>   value of an NSArray or NSDictionary
>   from Lua, and have the changes
>   reflected in Objective-C that won't
>   work right now, because Lua doesn't
>   get the actual reference to the
>   NSArray or NSDictionary back.  Corey

Source: http://groups.google.com/group/iphonewax/browse_thread/thread/3042002cddfadc9c